# Objects and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

Basically I'm trying to build an object that repeats the values from a query into the keys.

```
   $obj = new stdClass();
   $obj->Product =  (object) array("Name" => "", "Month"=> "", "Price" =>"");
   $obj->Totals = 0.00;

    $r=$shop->get_all_products(0);
   while(mysql_num_rows($r) && $row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
   {
    for ($i=$startMonth; $i<=$endMonth; $i++)
    {
        $thisDate=date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10));

        $r1=$reports->get_sales_by_month($i,$row['product_id']);
        while(mysql_num_rows($r1) && $row1=mysql_fetch_array($r1))
        {
           $totSales=$totSales + $row1['total_price'];
           $obj->Product->Name=$row['product_name'];
           $obj->Product->Month=$thisDate;
           $obj->Product->Price=$row1['total_price'];
           $obj->Totals=$totSales;
        }
    }
   }
```

When I do `var_dump($obj)`, I get only the last record in the query. I want the object to contain all records.

Comment: You're over-writing `$obj`'s values every time the loop runs - you'll need to either use different names (`Name1`, etc), or move the object instantiation code inside the while loop, and generate yourself an array of objects that way.

Comment: Also using `mysql_*` set of functions is deprecated - you should be looking at using `mysqli` or `pdo` objects.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Product Property needs to be an array if you want it to contain multiple values ...

Try this instead:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Product =  array();
$obj->Totals = 0.00;

$r=$shop->get_all_products(0);
while(mysql_num_rows($r) && $row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
 for ($i=$startMonth; $i<=$endMonth; $i++)
 {
     $thisDate=date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10));

     $r1=$reports->get_sales_by_month($i,$row['product_id']);
     while(mysql_num_rows($r1) && $row1=mysql_fetch_array($r1))
     {
        $totSales=$totSales + $row1['total_price'];
        $obj->Product[] = (object)array("Name"=>$row['product_name'], "Month"=>$thisDate, "Price"=>$row1['total_price']);
        $obj->Totals=$totSales;
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: nope... totals is an accumlation of the Price property on each product

Comment: Though this is correct, a common practice is to create an array of objects: $products[i]->name etc. In this way 1 record is always 1 object and 1 object always describes 1 thing/record/row.

Comment: @ChrisVisser this is an array of objects... i'm building as an array and casting to a `stdClass` object... the notation you use there will work in this use case

Comment: I know. I was just pointing it out. I upvoted and decided not to post my own version and instead I commented with another example

Comment: Thanks everyone. One last thing, to get to a product in January, I do something like $obj->Product["Month"]?